# How to remove "&#8362;" using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to print 2 numbers from website, but here's the output:
[image: Output]
This is the html code:

```
&#8362;2,499
```

This is my code:

```
def connectToUrl():
    print "Working:"
    opener = urllib2.build_opener()
    opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
    url = ""
    response = opener.open(url)
    page = response.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")

    before = str(soup.find('del')).split(";")[-1]
    after = str(soup.find('ins')).split(";")[-1]

    tag_re = re.compile(r'(<!--.*?-->|<[^>]*>)')
    no_tags_before = tag_re.sub('', str(before))
    no_tags_after = tag_re.sub('',str(after))

    before = cgi.escape(no_tags_before)
    after = cgi.escape(no_tags_after)

    return (before,after)
```

Comment: I am not sure if it is useful or works since I don't have python 2.7 for some reason, and can't be bothered installing (it is 3am here). But I had a similar problem once with beautiful soup. My solution was 
        `str(str(soup.findAll("div", {"class": "content"})).encode("utf-8"))`
Hope it helps!

Comment: @Stef2i Thank you :)

Comment: If it helped and you did fix the problem remember to post an answer for anyone else looking at this. :)